# Creating dummy rows in SAS from last entry date to specified date

Tags: database, syntax, sas

Suppose I have the following SAS dataset:

```
Account  Month  Balance  LastMonth   MonthDate    LastMonthDate
1        Jan    5        May         2012-01-01  2012-05-01
1        Feb    2        May         2012-02-01  2012-05-01
1        Mar    1        May         2012-03-01  2012-05-01
2        Feb    6        Apr         2012-02-01  2012-04-01
2        Mar    4        Apr         2012-03-01  2012-04-01
```

I need to create the following:

```
Account  Month  Balance  LastMonth   MonthDate    LastMonthDate
1        Jan    5        May         2012-01-01  2012-05-01
1        Feb    2        May         2012-02-01  2012-05-01
1        Mar    1        May         2012-03-01  2012-05-01
1        Apr    1        May         2012-04-01  2012-05-01
1        May    1        May         2012-05-01  2012-05-01
2        Feb    6        Apr         2012-02-01  2012-04-01
2        Mar    4        Apr         2012-03-01  2012-04-01
2        Apr    4        Apr         2012-04-01  2012-04-01
```

That is, I need to add additional rows, per account, so that each account has an entry for every month up to the 'LastMonth' column. For the months which are not in the original dataset, the balance must be kept constant with that of the last entry in the dataset. My dataset is already sorted by 'Account' and 'Month'.

Note that these are just two sample accounts, as my real dataset has multiple accounts, each with different 'LastMonth' columns. I need this process to be generalized so that this will create the number of missing lines for every account up to its' 'LastMonth' date.

Edit: The 'MonthDate' and 'LastMonthDate' are stored as follows:
[image]

Comment: are month_date and lastMonth_date character or date variables?

Comment: @DomPazz - they are SAS date formats (yymmdd10.)

Comment: Are they stored as dates or strings?  A format is a way to tell SAS how to display data.

Comment: @DomPazz - Please see the edit for a screenshot of the column properties :)

Comment: updated my answer for you.

Comment: Do you have SAS/ETS? If so, TIMESERIES will likely be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if you are on the last row of the account (requires the data be sorted by account).  Then convert your string months into numbers, iterate between them, and output the new month name.

**EDIT**

Based on comments, this data step will work with your data.  Kept the old answer for additional information:

```
data want;
set have;
by account;

output;

if last.account then do;
    /*Current month as a number*/
    month_n = month(MonthDate);
    /*LastMonth as a number*/
    to_month = month(LastMonthDate);

    do i=month_n+1 to to_month;
        month = put(mdy(i,1,2000),monname3.); /*Increment the month and write the month name*/
        output;
    end;
end;

drop month_n to_month i;
run;
```

**End EDIT**

Unfortunately SAS does not have an easy format or informat to convert between the months as strings and numbers.  So here I make them dates and extract the month number using the `month()` function:

```
data want;
set have;
by account;

output;

if last.account then do;
    /*Current month as a number*/
    month_n = month(input(catt("01",strip(month),"2000"),date9.));
    /*LastMonth as a number*/
    to_month = month(input(catt("01",lastMonth,"2000"),date9.));

    do i=month_n+1 to to_month;
        month = put(mdy(i,1,2000),monname3.); /*Increment the month and write the month name*/
        output;
    end;
end;

drop month_n to_month i;
run;
```

You could always create your own format and informat for the conversion.  This will make the code a bit cleaner.

```
proc format;
value MName 1="Jan"
             2="Feb"
             3="Mar"
             4="Apr"
             5="May"
             6="Jun"
             7="Jul"
             8="Aug"
             9="Sep"
             10="Oct"
             11="Nov"
             12="Dec";

invalue MName "Jan"=1
             "Feb"=2
             "Mar"=3
             "Apr"=4
             "May"=5
             "Jun"=6
             "Jul"=7
             "Aug"=8
             "Sep"=9
             "Oct"=10
             "Nov"=11
             "Dec"=12;
run;

data want2;
set have;
by account;

output;

if last.account then do;
    /*Current month as a number*/
    month_n = input(month,MName.);
    /*LastMonth as a number*/
    to_month = input(lastMonth,MName.);

    do i=month_n+1 to to_month;
        month = put(i,MName.);
        output;
    end;
end;

drop month_n to_month i;
run;
```

Comment: I also have a field where both the 'Month' and 'LastMonth' are stored in an actual date format (yymmddn10.) - would it be easier to have cleaner code when using those variables instead? I will edit them in now so you can see.

Comment: sure just change `month_n = month(input(catt("01",strip(month),"2000"),date9.));` to `month_n = month(month_date_var);` (if they are SAS dates) or `month_n = month(input(month_date_var,yymmdd10.));` if it is a string.

Comment: I edited the question now to show the date formatted variables as well

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using a DOW loop approach.  It does **not** require a 'pre-pass' of the data to evaluate and enumerate the monotonic months covering each accounts date range.

The key concepts are

- using LAG and INTCK to find with-in group month gaps
- using INTNX to compute loop iterants
- maintaining state with support variables later dropped

**Sample Code**

Presumes `month` and `lastmonth` are proper date variables

```
data have;
attrib account format=8. month format=yymon7. informat=date9. lastmonth format=yymon7. informat=date9.;
input
Account  Month        Balance  LastMonth; datalines;
1        01-Jan-18    5        01-May-18
1        01-Feb-18    2        01-May-18
1        01-Mar-18    1        01-May-18
2        01-Feb-18    6        01-Apr-18
2        01-Mar-18    4        01-Apr-18
3        01-Jan-18    15       01-May-18
3        01-Mar-18    11       01-May-18
run;

data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.account);

    set have;
    by account;

    prior_month = lag(month);
    prior_balance = lag(balance);

    * fill-in gaps within group;
    if _n_ > 1 and intck('month', prior_month, month) > 1 then do;
      curr_month = month;
      curr_balance = balance;

      balance = prior_balance;

      gap_start = intnx('month', prior_month, 1);
      gap_end   = intnx('month', curr_month, -1);

      * repeat prior observed months data for missing months;
      do month = gap_start by 0 until (month >= gap_end);
        OUTPUT;
        put 'NOTE: ' account= 'within-group gap data output ' month= balance=;

        month = intnx('month', month, 1);
      end;

      * restore original state;
      month = curr_month;
      balance = curr_balance;
    end;

    * unconditional output for within group data;
    OUTPUT;
  end;

  gap_start = intnx('month', month, 1);
  gap_end   = intnx('month', lastmonth, 0); * just for saftey sake;

  * conditional output for post-group months using data from last row in group ;
  do month = gap_start by 0 until (month > gap_end);
    OUTPUT;
    put 'NOTE: ' account= '  post-group gap data output ' month= balance=;    
    month = intnx('month', month, 1);
  end;

  drop prior_: curr_: gap_:;
run;
```